# Translate pixels from cropped section of image to original image OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am using OpenCV in Python. I have used the following code to select and copy a section of a main image into a sub-image:

```
boundingBoxRotatedRect = cv2.minAreaRect(boxPoints)
if boundingBoxRotatedRect[2] < -45:
    boundingBoxRotatedRect = (boundingBoxRotatedRect[0], (boundingBoxRotatedRect[1][1],boundingBoxRotatedRect[1][0]), boundingBoxRotatedRect[2] + 90)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(boundingBoxRotatedRect[0], boundingBoxRotatedRect[2], 1.0)  
size = np.int0(boundingBoxRotatedRect[1])
size = (size[0],size[1])
dst = cv2.warpAffine(mainImage, M, (mainImage.shape[1], mainImage.shape[0]))
subImage = cv2.getRectSubPix(dst, size, boundingBoxRotatedRect[0])
```

Where boxPoints is an array of 4 points making up the bounding box around the area to be cropped from the main image, boundingBoxRotatedRect is the same box represented as a rotated rect object, M is the rotation matrix, size is the width/height of the bounding box, mainImage is the main image being cropped from, and subImage is ultimately the final image that has been cropped from the main image. The picture linked below further explains what is happening.

[Explanation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOJlH.png)

My question is: If I use OpenCV drawing functions to edit the subImage, how can I put those same drawings back onto the corresponding pixels of the mainImage? So for example (if using the image shapes in my provided Explanation Image) I draw an upright smiley face on the subImage, how can I translate that into the correctly oriented diagonal smiley face in the correct location on the mainImage?

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. Homography!

Replace above code with:

```
#If bottomLeft = true, boxPoints[0] corresponds to btm-lft corner of subImage. 
#If bottomLeft = false, boxPoints[0] corresponds to btm-right corner of subImage. 
bottomLeft = True 

boundingBoxRotatedRect = cv2.minAreaRect(boxPoints)
if boundingBoxRotatedRect[2] < -45:
    boundingBoxRotatedRect = (boundingBoxRotatedRect[0], (boundingBoxRotatedRect[1][1],boundingBoxRotatedRect[1][0]), boundingBoxRotatedRect[2] + 90)
    bottomLeft = False
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(boundingBoxRotatedRect[0], boundingBoxRotatedRect[2], 1.0)  
size = np.int0(boundingBoxRotatedRect[1])
size = (size[0],size[1])
dst = cv2.warpAffine(mainImage, M, (mainImage.shape[1], mainImage.shape[0]))
subImage = cv2.getRectSubPix(dst, size, boundingBoxRotatedRect[0])

#Get homography matrix
if bottomLeft:
    pts_src = np.array([[0, size[0] - 1], [0, 0], [size[1] - 1, 0],[size[1] - 1, size[0] - 1]])
else:
    pts_src = np.array([[size[1] - 1, size[0] - 1], [0, size[0] - 1], [0, 0], [size[1] - 1, 0]])
pts_dst = boxPoints
h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)


## BELOW, REPLACE "[x, y], [X2, Y2], ...]" WITH LIST OF POINTS FROM SUBIMAGE TO BE TRANSLATED TO MAINIMAGE
a = np.array([[x, y], [X2, Y2], ...] dtype='float32')
a = np.array([a])
pointsOut = cv2.perspectiveTransform(a, h)
pointsOut = pointsOut[0]

#Then use the points in pointsOut to draw whatever you want!
```